# Base Number Problem Solving

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the small hamlet of Abaze, two base systems are in common use. Also, everyone speaks the truth. One resident said, "26 people use my base, base 10, and only 22 people speak base 14." (Note that all four of the numbers 26, 10, 22, and 14 are to be interpreted in this resident's base, not base ten.) Another said, "Of the 25 residents, 13 are bilingual and 1 can't use either base." (Again, all these numbers are to be interpreted in this resident's base, not base ten.) How many residents are there? Express the answer in base ten.

I have no idea what this question means - it's very confusing, and I don't understand how the information the residents of Abaze give can help you find out how many residents live there. :(

Comment: Consider taking the number of bilingual residents shifted into "base $10$" away from each of the listed quantities of how many know each base.  Then add those numbers together and compare with the shifted count of residents which must know only one or the other base.

Comment: Let the first resident's base be $a$ and the other $b$.  Then there are $2a+6$ that use base $a$ and $2a+2$ that use base $b$.  On the other hand, there are $2b+5$ total residents.  That gives you one equation.  Now use the rest of what you are given to get another.

Comment: Note that Ross failed to take into account the $b + 3$ residents that use both bases, and the $1$ resident incapable of using either in putting together the first equation. The other equation between $a$ and $b$ is given by the first resident, when the call the other base than they are using "$14$".

Comment: I have one equation now: $1+(2a+6)+(2a+2)-b-3=2b+5$, where 1 is the person who can't speak either language, $2a+6$ is the number of people who speak base "$10$" (including bilingual), $2a+2$ is the number of people who speak base "$14$" (including bilingual), and $b+3$ is the number of people who are bilingual (so you subtract). This simplifies to $4a=3b-1$. But since there are two variables, I need another equation...